# How to select the first matched element for each unique attribute value with Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a feature in an application. I use Javascript to append an indicator to an element. I add a class to elements that need an indicator, but some elements are loaded multiple times, causing multiple indicators to show and I only want to show one per element. Every element that has such a class, also has an attribute with a unique data-connect-id (only it's not unique anymore when it's loaded onto the page multiple times).

Now, how do I only append the indicator to every first match per unique attribute value? This works for one:

```
$(".connector[data-connect-id = '2']").first().append("<div class='indicator'></div>");
```

But that's only for one specified data-connect-id. It should look for all unique data-connect-id's, but how do I do that?

Comment: Have you try this ? [JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to spin through the doc and add the indicator div to the first element with a given `data-connect-id` value, without knowing the values in advance. I can't think of anything more elegant than a loop:

```
var seen = {};
$(".connector[data-connect-id]").each(function() {
    var connector = $(this);
    var id = connector.attr("data-connect-id");
    if (!seen[id]) {
        connector.append(/*...*/);
        seen[id] = true;
    }
});
```

I mean, you *could* collect all the IDs in advance, and then do a loop with your `first` example, but it would be less efficient.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. I should've been more clear about the ID. It's not an actual ID. It's a custom attribute called data-connect-id. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joris508: I did wonder if you were just using the general term. :-)